# How to support Association Classes using GMF?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-gef, eclipse-gmf

Trying to figure out how to support Association Classes using GMF.  I need to produce diagrams like this:
[image]

I can create the classes fine (`Node` Figures), and similarly simple associations.  However: I'm not sure how to handle the Association Class. I think I want:

- A `Connection` to represent the main Association (solid line)
- A `Connection Anchor` on the mid-point of the Association Connection
- Another `Connection` joining the Association Class to the mid point `Connection Anchor`

I don't want to use a `Node` in the middle of the Association since that will create an unwanted bend point.

So specific questions:

1. Is the approach above reasonable/sensible?
2. Is there a better way to do it?
3. Any pointers to existing implementations?  This must have been solved for each of the many GEF/GMF-based UML editors but some protracted googling hasn't surfaced anything.

Thanks.